# MUI masonry Component flickers when rendering more

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create an image "gallery" of sorts. Each image may have a unique height and be displayed in columns. Mui's [Masonry component](https://v5-0-6.mui.com/components/masonry/) is perfect.

It allows me to render not only simple image tags but complex animated images with labels.

The way I implemented it is that when you click a button it loads 10 more items next to the existing ones. However, it flickers when the new images are loaded. As per my understanding after reading this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/36673) I think it does it so it can measure the height of each component. This is very annoying and I have no idea how to fix it. I can't "hide" the component because that would look weird while loading. Is there a way to get rid, of or make less obvious or invisible this flicker? Why aren't the elements invisible by default when the height is measured?

If there is no fix, is there another library/component that would fit this use case?

The logic of my code looks something like this:

```
function Galery() {
  const isBelowWidth = useMediaQuery(600);

  const [maxShownItems, setMaxShownItems] = useState(10);

  const galeryItems = [{url:, alt:}]

  const onShowMore = () => {
    setMaxShownItems(maxShownItems + 10);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        maxWidth: "1000px",
        margin: "auto",
      }}
    >
      <Masonry columns={isBelowWidth ? 2 : 3} spacing={1}>
        {galeryItems.map((item, index) => {
          if (index < maxShownItems) {
            return (
              <motion.div
                key={index}
                style={{
                  opacity: 0,
                  transform: "translateY(60px)",
                  transition: `opacity 1s ease-in-out, transform 1s ease-in-out`,
                }}
                animate={{
                  opacity: 1,
                  transform: "translateY(0px)",
                }}
                transition={{
                  opacity: {
                    duration: 0.3,
                    delay: (index % 10) * 0.1,
                  },
                  transform: {
                    duration: 0.3,
                    delay: (index % 10) * 0.1,
                  },
                }}
              >
                <img
                  src={`${item.url}`}
                  alt={item.alt}
                  loading="lazy"
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: "5px",
                    display: "block",
                    width: "100%",
                  }}
                />
              </motion.div>
            );
          }
        })}
      </Masonry>

      <div
        style={{
          display: galeryItems.length > maxShownItems ? "flex" : "none",
          justifyContent: "center",
          marginTop: "15px",
        }}
      >
        <button
          onClick={onShowMore}
        >
          Show More
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I think you may mean masonry not missionary?

Comment: Edited. Thats gotta by the funniest autocorrect ever.

Comment: Could you have two copies. One being seen by the user, the other adding the 10 new images, then swap, perhaps using CSS visibility. Otherwise I think I’d scrap using this code and write from scratch, loading new images out of site first before adding them to the visible stuff.  I’d also have the next 10 images loaded in advance and waiting out of site so there is no pause when the user clicks for more.